# Efficiently calculate the number of equal-value-pairs in array with O(nlogn) time O(1) space

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates

Given an array of `int` values:

```
{4, 2, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5}
```

the index of qualified pairs are

```
{0, 4}
{0, 5}
{4, 5}
{3, 6}
```

the 2nd index should be greater than the 1st index. So the correct result is 4.

Please note worst-case time complexity is O(nlogn), worst-case space complexity is O(1).

Naive solution: two loops, but O(n^2).

My solution: quick sort the array, then become `{2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6}`, calculate the number of element if it appears more than once: e.g.: the number of 4 is 3, count+=3*2/2=3, the number of 5 is 2, count+=2*1/2=1.

Problem of my solution: worst-case can have O(n^2), but it requires O(1) space, so i didn't choose merge sort.

Could anyone help give a good solution? Thank you.

Comment: instead of sorting the array you can iterate over it once and count the number of occurrences of each element - a space/time trade-off that will result in O(n) for both

Comment: @TerryStorm That is the difficult part of this question. Otherwise, Collection can be used to calculate frequency of each element.

Comment: Okay, it is a requirement instead of an observation

Comment: Btw sorting can be done in O (n log n) so your algorithm is okay, if you use e.g. heapsort

Comment: So use [Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) to sort the array in place. That's O(n log n) time, and O(1) space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest code I can think if is to use a Set:

```
int duplicateCount = 0;
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int n : numbers)
    if (!set.add(n))
        duplicateCount++;
```

Or java 8:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
int dups = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(n -> !set.add(n)).count();
```

The add() method of Set returns true if the addition changed the set (ie it was a new number), false otherwise (ie it is a duplicate).

HashSet has excellent performance - O(1) - and the algorithm is O(n) performance and (depending on distribution) < O(n) space.

---

If you really need O(1) space, you could sort the array using [`Arrays.sort(int\[\])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) (whose implementation in Java 7 onward uses a Dual-Pivot Quicksort, which is an in-place - ie O(1) - algorithm) then add this code:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
int dups = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
    if (numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1])
        dups++;
```

`Arrays.sort()` is very efficient O(nlogn) and there's no extra space used O(1).

Comment: A crucial requirement here is the O (1) space. A set doesnt accomplish this

Comment: Are you certain that `Arrays.sort()` has a *worst case* time of O(n log n)? And you're *certain* that it uses no extra space (like, no recursion)?

Comment: This solution for the OP's array - {4, 2, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5} results 3. But output should be 4

Comment: @Jim Yes, I'm sure it's O(1) space. Starting with Java 7, the implementation of `Arrays.sort()` for arrays of primitives (as in this question) uses the Dual-Pivot Quicksort, which is O(1) space (in-place). `Arrays.sort()` for arrays of object uses TimSort, which is near O(1) for almost sorted arrays or worst case n/2 space for random starting order,

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
        private static int GetCount(int count)
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (count + 1) * count / 2;
    }

    public static int solution1(int[] a)
    {
        Array.Sort(a);
        int count = 0;
        int currentCount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i - 1] == a[i])
            {
                currentCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                count += GetCount(currentCount);
                currentCount = 0;
            }
        }
        count += GetCount(currentCount);
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    // make count of each element
    for (int element : A) {
        if (map.containsKey(element)) {
            map.put(element, map.get(element) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(element, 1);
        }
    }
    // count number of pair of pairs
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .mapToInt(IdenticalPair::countPair).sum();
}

private static int countPair(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry) {
    /**
     * ((elementCount - 1)) * elementCount / 2;
     * (1-1)*1/2 = 0
     * (2-1)*2/2 = 1
     * (3-1)*3/2 = 3
     * (4-1)*4/2 = 6
     * and so on.....
     */
    return ((entry.getValue() - 1)) * entry.getValue() / 2;
}
```